# How to use \ifdefined inside align*

Tags: conditionals, tex4ht

I need to use `\ifdefined` inside `align` to tell latex to use different code for pdf and for tex4ht. But it gives an error.

Is there any way around this (other than putting the `ifdefined` outside everything, which will complicate things for me.

Here is MW

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}    
R_{2} = R_{2}-R_{1} &\Longrightarrow\hspace{5pt}
\ifdefined\HCode
   \left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
                       0&0&4&0\\ 
                       0&0&0&0\\ 
                       0&0&2&0 
          \end{array}
    \right]               
\else
     \left[             
         \begin{array}{@{}ccc!{\color{red}\vline width 0.6pt}c@{}}
                       0&0&4&0\\ 
                       0&0&0&0\\ 
                       0&0&2&0
         \end{array}
     \right]               
\fi      
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Compiling with `lualatex` gives error

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-PalatinoLinotype.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg))
! Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 21.
<inserted text>
\fi
<*> foo3.tex

?
```

TL 2020

Comment: @campa it does not work for me. Did it work on your end? still same error.

Comment: It did, but I've got TeX Live 2017.

Comment: @campa I was using same code I have but added {}{} as you suggested but did not work. May be I did something wrong. But it works now using `\ifdef{HCode}` as shown in answer below. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. They are all very good and all worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put it in a group:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}    
R_{2} = R_{2}-R_{1} &\Longrightarrow\hspace{5pt}
{\ifdefined\HCode
   \left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
                       0&0&4&0\\ 
                       0&0&0&0\\ 
                       0&0&2&0 
          \end{array}
    \right]               
\else
     \left[             
         \begin{array}{@{}ccc!{\color{red}\vline width 0.6pt}c@{}}
                       0&0&4&0\\ 
                       0&0&0&0\\ 
                       0&0&2&0
         \end{array}
     \right]               
\fi}     
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But I don't see why you repeat the matrix in each branch,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}    
R_{2} = R_{2}-R_{1} &\Longrightarrow\hspace{5pt}
\left[
\begin{array}{@{}ccc!{\ifdefined\HCode |\else\color{red}\vline width 0.6pt\fi}c@{}}
                       0&0&4&0\\ 
                       0&0&0&0\\ 
                       0&0&2&0 
          \end{array}
    \right]               
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Primitive `\if` commands are difficult. You often have to ensure that the `\else` and `\fi` are found before the branch is executed. Use a user command like `\ifdef` from etoolbox which hides this from you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
R_{2} = R_{2}-R_{1} &\Longrightarrow\hspace{5pt}
\ifdef{\HCode}
   {\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccc|c@{}}
                       0&0&4&0\\
                       0&0&0&0\\
                       0&0&2&0
          \end{array}
    \right]}
   {\left[
         \begin{array}{@{}ccc!{\color{red}\vline width 0.6pt}c@{}}
                       0&0&4&0\\
                       0&0&0&0\\
                       0&0&2&0
         \end{array}
     \right]}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```